# connect database postgresql to ruby on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have created a database on postgreSQL with username = "quiz_test" and pass = "1" on pgAdmin. I want to connect my rails application named: "quiz_test" to the database and get an error. Someone can help me ?

[image]

I use the following commands on terminal:

```
echo 'export QUIZ_TEST_DATABASE_PASSWORD="1"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

change the file database.yml

```
username: quiz_test
password: <%= ENV['QUIZ_TEST_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
rails db:create
```

and I get the error shown.

Comment: when i use command on terminal :rails server --binding=127.0.0.1

Comment: welcome to SO! Please add your GitHub repo link if possible and database.yml file.